# Lucid with belongs to many

Tags: node.js, orm, adonis.js

I have a problem in two many to many relationships, I will show the diagram to see if clear.

Diagram:

[image: 1]

Model of User:

```
  user_vehicle_types () {
    return this.belongsToMany('App/Models/VehicleType').pivotTable(
      'user_vehicle_types'
    )
  }
```

Model of Vehicle Type:

```
  liberation_types () {
    return this.manyThrough('App/Models/UserVehicleType', 'liberation_types')
  }
```

Model Of User Vehicle Type:

```
  liberation_types () {
    return this.belongsToMany(
      'App/Models/AccessLiberationType'
    ).pivotTable('user_liberation_types')
  }
```

The problem that is occurring is that it is bringing release types, from other users the vehicle types come right. I believe the way I made the relationships is wrong, if anyone can help me, I appreciate it.